# how to leave keyboard open in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating a page where I want to leave keyboard open the whole time user is on it. also there Entry is hidden

after research on google for few hours. I found that, you can hide a Entry on page and set Focus() on back-end code

issue is that, Focus() method isn't seem to be working on hidden Entry.

CreatePage.xaml - basic hidden entry

```
<Entry x:Name="MyEntry" IsVisible="false"></Entry>
```

CreatePage.xaml.cs - back-end code

```
public partial class CreatePage: ContentPage
{
    public CreatePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        MyEntry.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: if no solution, I guess I can create keypad using 9 buttons-view on fron-end, and get onTap Event on backend. Only issue with this is why build your own keypad if its already exists in android

Comment: If that's for pin only, custom buttons is an option, as both Android and iOS are using 9 buttons-view for unlocking the phone and most other apps with pin pwd, might be for better security.

Comment: thanks, yes i think that might be for the best

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with `MyEntry.Focus();`,you just need to add a little delay.

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
     base.OnAppearing();
     await Task.Delay(200);
     MyEntry.Focus();
}
```

Comment: just added a delay but no luck. I was hoping that would work tho

Comment: btw, i added breakpoints on each of those lines. seem like its running them but no result

Comment: @StarGates Are you on the first page of an app that doesn't pop up the keyboard? Or you can try increasing the delay like `await Task.Delay(600);`,it works on my side .

Comment: thank for getting back to me. do you think I can take a look at your project code? Yes, I only have 1 page in my application

Comment: btw, keyboard does popup, only if entry is visible. when you hide Entry than it doesnt popup

Comment: If the issue is that the entry has to be visible you can simply create a custom entry that has no real color to it so it is "invisible"